# Google OAuth2 SignIn method fires at page load

Tags: google-oauth

I have used the official button for Google SignIn:

**SignIn Page:**

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="AuthenticateGoogleUser"></div>

function AuthenticateGoogleUser(googleUser){
    .....
    capture the user info and redirect to Home page
    .....
}
```

When configuring for the credentials, I have set the redirection URL to the signin page.

This is how the Signout happens for the app:

```
function SignOutGoogleUser() {
    if (gapi != null && gapi != undefined &&
        gapi.auth2 != null && gapi.auth2 != undefined) {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            auth2.disconnect();    
            ....Redirect to Home page...        
        });
    }
}
```

The methods work fine. If I signout, will be redirected to home page.
But, when I manually browse the SignIn page after signout, the `AuthenticateGoogleUser` method is triggered and I am auto signed into the app (with google account).

The `AuthenticateGoogleUser` method should be only triggered on the button click. Is that right.
But here it is being triggered on load of SignIn page. Is that expected. Can this be stopped.

I'm using MVC C# as backend.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all of your code, I am working on the assumption that you have not placed the function in a document ready wrapper and made sure to only kick it off on a button click or other event from which you would like to have it fire.  As it stands now, it will fire on that page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("btnLogin").click(function(){
      AuthenticateGoogleUser(googleUser);
   });
});
```

Comment: You are right. The method is not inside a document-ready wrapper.
But, the button is dynamically generated inside the `g-signin2` div and so, I did not write any button click event also. The button click functionality is happening by itself.

Comment: Try temporarily removing 
    data-onsuccess="AuthenticateGoogleUser"
It may be that this is what is causing the behavior.  I believe that line is supposed to be there though.